# How do i make state reset inside nested routes

Tags: reactjs

I've noticed every time the profile:id is changed to one and another(/profile/1 -> profile/2), the state inside the profile component isn't changed.

Is there a way to "reset" the component state when the :id is changed? I am having trouble trying to figure this out.

My code looks something like this

`<Route path ='/profile/:id/' component={ Profile } />`

```
componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
 }
componentWillUnmount(){
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
    }
trackScrolling = () => {
        const wrappedElement = document.getElementById('lastElement');
        if (this.isBottom(wrappedElement)) {
            this.setState({render_count: this.state.render_count+1});
        }
};
isBottom(el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Grab the id from the url using `match.params` from props
- Use `componentDidUpdate` to change the state of the component

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
     this.setState({
      render_count: 0
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and it did not work. If you type `console.log(this.state.render_count)` below you still get the previous render_count.

Comment: @James, state updates are asynchronous and hence you will you see the the updated state post the render

Comment: However, I got another function after this.setState. When that functions running it does not the render_count to 0

Comment: where and how you are executing the function(which logs render_count). Also share more code , it will be helpful to suggest ... In general the updated state will appear in the next re-render cycle(coz state updates are aysnc)..